# python stop updating variables

Tags: python, variables, time, pygame

I wrote this program which stops the time from the beginning of the program. But it want to display the time when I open the window and not when I start the code.
This is my function for the time right now:

```py
def Time():
    global myfont,minute
    realtime = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000   
    time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000 - minute*60 - realtime) 
    if time < 10:
        label = myfont.render("Zeit: "+ str(minute) + ":0" + str(time) , 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(label, (x - 190, 20))
    else:
        label = myfont.render("Zeit: "+ str(minute) + ":" + str(time) , 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(label, (x - 190, 20))
        
    if time / 60 == 1:
        minute +=1
        time = 0
        label = myfont.render("Zeit: "+ str(minute) + ":" + str(time) , 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(label, (x - 190, 20))
```

I tried it by substracting the time that it ran until there with realtime. But the variable realtime keeps updating the same as time so it would display 0. Is there any way how I can take the value of realtime at the moment when I open the window?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Is there any way how I can take the value of realtime at the moment when I open the window?" How about if you... put the code that decides the value of `realtime`... at the point in the code that the window opens? Or at least, at the first time that the code does something to update the window? It's clear that you're already comfortable with global variables. How about if you have one that represents that initial time?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `start_time` variable when you open the window:

```py
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Calculate the time difference in `Time`:

```py
def Time():
    global myfont,minute

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 
    delta_time = current_time - start_time

    realtime = delta_time / 1000   
    time = int(delta_time / 1000 - minute*60 - realtime) 

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it now but the - realtime at the end  is usless. without it it works fine.